# data member int reference

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference

I a trying to store int by reference as data member of class.
I expected that is object get int by refernce than if I increase the reference from outside its increase the value inside the object.

```
class A
{
private :
    int& x;

public:
    A(int y) : x(y)
    {
        cout << "A's ctor x = " << x << endl;
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    }


};

int main()
{
    int i = 8;
    A a(i);
    a.print();
    ++i;
    a.print();
}
```

The output is :

```
A's ctor x = 8
x = 8
x = 8
```

Why x isnt 9?

Comment: What do you think `x` *was* (note the tense) referencing? Hint: it isn't `i`. Spoiler: `A(int& y)`. Turn up your warning levels. You should have received a warning to the effect of "Binding reference member 'x' to stack allocated parameter 'y'"

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that you're binding a temporary (the constructor parameter `y`) to a reference. The lifetime of the temporary is restricted to the constructor, but your reference lives on, becoming a "dangling" reference. This is what a reasonable compiler has to say about the matter:

> crap13.cpp:10:18: warning: binding reference member 'x' to stack allocated parameter 'y' [-Wdangling-field]
>
> A(int y) : x(y)

You can "fix" this by making the constructor parameter a reference:

```
A(int& y) : x(y)
```

but you must ensure that whatever is passed as argument to the constructor outlives the object being constructed.

Comment: Is that gcc's warning? clang gives the same messaging, but doesn't note the warning flag attributing to the emission. Just curious. (like the filename, btw =P)

Comment: @WhozCraig It is some reasonably new version of clang, as bundled with with xcode.

Comment: That's the one I use. Latest update (I think) : *Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)*. Odd. Thanks.

Comment: @WhozCraig I got *Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)*, after a recent OS upgrade.

Comment: Are you running El Capitan ? I'm still on Yosemite. May be related. I just can't get the hutzpah to pull the lever yet.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, running el Cap. I bit the bullet, and it was way less painful than expected. Had to uninstall all macports and re-install but that was relatively straightforward.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the info. Ports is where my valgrind originates, so I'll make a note of that. Thanks again.

Comment: Doesn't a reference extend the lifetime of the object it refers to, to the reference's own lifetime? If not, how could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are passing int by value in your constructor, you should pass it by reference:

```
A(int& y) : x(y)
{
    cout << "A's ctor x = " << x << endl;
}
```